# Buscar conteúdo de acordo com preenchimento de duas Combobox

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Na página inicial do meu site preciso ter duas combobox para o usuário selecionar opções vindas do banco de dados (por exemplo: seleciona o estado na primeira combobox e ao selecionar o estado na segunda combobox são carregadas as cidades deste estado. Até aí, ok.). Estou encontrando dificuldades ao fazer o seguinte: Após o usuário preencher as duas combobox (escolher estado e cidade), preciso que nessa mesma tela, abaixo das combos, apareça um texto de acordo com as opções selecionadas. Esse conteúdo virá do banco e será de acordo com o id do estado e o id da cidade selecionada.

Meu select em HTML é populado e a cada estado selecionado uma função JavaScript chama um arquivo chamado listaCidades.php que irá preencher a outra combobox. Ok. Como pegar o id do estado e o id da cidade e fazer uma consulta usando essas duas informações para trazer conteúdo na mesma tela inicial?

Comment: Coloque alguns código já existentes da parte em questão, para facilitar a resposta e apresentar melhor suas dúvidas. Pelo que eu entendi você quer só pegar o id e estado, isso daria pra você fazer com javascript para pegar os id's necessários e utilizando ajax para enviar pro arquivo chamado `listaCidades.php`, neste arquivo você retorna um JSON e com JS você consegue montar dinâmicamente o texto de acordo.

Comment: Amigo, neste caso acredito que você tenha a informação completa (estado/cidade) após o usuario selecionar um valor na combobox cidade não é mesmo ? Então você pode escultar o evento onchange da combobox cidade para quando ela for alterada, fazer uma requisição ao servidor passando os valores selecionados das duas combobox. Quando você posta o seu codigo fica mais facil de dizer quais alterações você precisa fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como pegar o id do estado e o id da cidade e fazer uma consulta usando essas duas informações para trazer conteúdo na mesma tela inicial?

---

**É possível fazer isso com AJAX.**

Aqui vão os passos:

- Primeiro faça o combobox do estado e preencha com os estados do banco de dados via loop PHP ou use uma framework, como o AngularJS.
- No evento "onchange" do combobox, coloque pra executar uma função JavaScript. Ex: onchange="CarregarCidades(this.value)".

O parâmetro "this.value" pega automaticamente o valor do estado selecionado.

- Crie a função JavaScript mencionada no exemplo - "CarregaCidades(idEstado)" - e, dentro dela, coloque uma chamada AJAX que vai executar funções/métodos PHP e retornar um array contendo as cidades. Exemplo de AJAX:

  ```
  $.ajax({
    url:'paginaAlvo.php',
    type:'GET',
    data: {id: idEstado},
    success:function(data){
      // Preenche o combobox das cidades
    }
  });
  ```

---

Obs: para saber como fazer a query em PHP e recebê-la pelo AJAX em forma de array, veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220642/pass-php-array-into-javascript-array.

---

- Agora, faça o AJAX preencher o combobox das cidades. Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array.

---

Se quiser um tutorial mais completo, pesquise na Internet. Para facilitar, listo aqui alguns bem legais:

http://www.marcelokenji.com.br/carregar-combobox-de-cidadeestado-com-ajaxphpmysql/

http://www.devfuria.com.br/javascript/forms/select-combobox/